# Foreign key model values return same value

Tags: django, django-models

I have looked at all answer and nothing quite helps me. I have a model Group

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_num   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type        = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

and a model Subgroup group

```
class Subgroup(models.Model):
    sub_group_num   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_group_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group_number    = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='group_numbers', verbose_name="Group Number")
    group_in_name   = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='group_names', verbose_name="Group Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_group_name
```

when I reference the group_number and group_in_name from subgroup they give the same value in the template

The template is

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                  <label>Group Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 form-group">
                  {{ form.group_number }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label>Group Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 form-group">
                  {{ form.group_in_name }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1 mb-1">Add Sub Group</button>
                </div>
```

And view is

```
class AddSubGroupView(CreateView):
    model = Subgroup
    form_class = AddSubgroupForm
    template_name = 'lookups/add_subgroup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Why you are referencing same model `Group` two times? You don't need to duplicate it

Comment: the model Group has 2 columns (name and number) and I want to have those to columns in the subgroup model

Comment: Please share the template part and views as well

Comment: You can access those columns from single foreign key

Comment: I have added the views and template

Comment: How do I access from single foreign key